# Populate checkbox value in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a checkboxes in my form. Lets say i created one record with 'Telegram' checked and 'What's up unchecked. When I edit the form i want to see telegram already checked for me. This is what i try:

```html
<%= check_box_tag 'social[]', "Telegram", @user.social.include?("Telegram ") %>
```

so third parameter sets checked value of my check box properly. I want to use only one partial called form with that piece of code. If I use this code for new I will get an obvious error:

```html
undefined method `include?' for nil
```

Of course for new method i have no @user.social = nil. 
I could just create different form inside new.html.erb with

```html
 <%= check_box_tag 'social[]', "Telegram" %>
```

like that, but i want DRY solution

Answer (score 0):

While I was waiting for answer, i tried this and it worked.

In application_helper:

```html
  def set_social_checkbox(model, check_box_text )
    if model.social.present?
      model.social.include?(check_box_text)
    else
      false
    end
  end
```

and in form i use it like that:

```html
set_social_checkbox(@user,'What\'s up')
```